# iOS CALayer convertPoint:fromLayer: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, xcode, calayer, uibezierpath

I have a class with a square made of bezierPaths, you can change the size of the square by pressing near a side and drag it.

Right now i can drag and release one time, the next time i get the following error:

2015-01-20 14:20:36.356 BezierPaths[196:3437] *** -[CALayer convertPoint:fromLayer:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1742251c0

Why doesnt it work the 2nd time?

This is the class:

```
@implementation EditBezierView
{
    UIBezierPath *path;
    UIImage *incrementalImage;
    CGPoint pts[9];

    NSMutableArray *pathPoints;
    NSMutableArray *controlPoints;

    BOOL pressedPoint;
    int index;

    float xStart;
    float yStart;

    int closestIndex;
    CGPoint closestComparePoint;
    bool moveControl;

    int counter;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:1.0];
        pathPoints = [NSMutableArray array];
        controlPoints = [NSMutableArray array];
    }



    return self;

}
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
        path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
        counter = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initValues
{

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(47.0, 130.0)]];
    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(14.0, 230.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(26.0, 150.0)]];

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(22.0, 320.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(9.0, 270.0)]];

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(90.0, 420.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(24.0, 380.0)]];

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(230.0, 420.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(170.0, 460.0)]];

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(300.0, 320.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(280.0, 390)]];

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(307.0, 220.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(315.0, 260.0)]];

    [pathPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(270.0, 130.0)]];
    [controlPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(300.0, 160.0)]];

    [self drawPaths];
}

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}



- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    counter++;
    NSLog(@"%d", counter);
    [self.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
   UITouch *currentTouch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint startPt = [currentTouch locationInView:self];


    if(moveControl)
    {
        float xOs = [(NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:closestIndex] CGPointValue].x;
        float yOs = [(NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:closestIndex] CGPointValue].y;
        [controlPoints replaceObjectAtIndex:closestIndex withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xOs - (xStart-startPt.x), yOs - (yStart - startPt.y))]];
    }
    else
    {
        float xOs = [(NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:closestIndex] CGPointValue].x;
        float yOs = [(NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:closestIndex] CGPointValue].y;
        [pathPoints replaceObjectAtIndex:closestIndex withObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(xOs - (xStart-startPt.x), yOs - (yStart - startPt.y))]];

    }
    [self drawPaths];

    xStart = startPt.x;
    yStart = startPt.y;
}


- (void)drawPaths
{
    path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    for(int i = 1; i < [pathPoints count]; i++)
    {
        //Draw path
        [path moveToPoint:((NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i-1]).CGPointValue];
        [path addQuadCurveToPoint:((NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i]).CGPointValue controlPoint:((NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i-1]).CGPointValue];

        //Draw points
        if(i == 1)
        {
            [self addrectangle:((NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i-1]).CGPointValue];
            [self addrectangle:((NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i]).CGPointValue];
            [self addQuadrectangle:((NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i-1]).CGPointValue];
        }
        else
        {
            [self addrectangle:((NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i]).CGPointValue];
            [self addQuadrectangle:((NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i-1]).CGPointValue];
        }
    }
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *currentTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint startPt = [currentTouch locationInView:self];
    closestComparePoint = startPt;
    xStart = startPt.x;
    yStart = startPt.y;
    [self findNearestPoint];
    }



- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    //[self drawPath];
}

-(void)findNearestPoint
{
    int pathClosestIndex = 0;
    CGFloat xDist;
    CGFloat yDist;
    CGFloat Controldistance = 12401240;
    CGFloat Pathdistance = 12401240;
    for(int i = 0; i < [controlPoints count]; i++)
    {
        xDist = ABS([(NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x - closestComparePoint.x);
        yDist = ABS([(NSValue*)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y - closestComparePoint.y);
        if(sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)) < Controldistance)
        {
            Controldistance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
            closestIndex = i;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < [pathPoints count]; i++)
    {
        xDist = ABS([(NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x - closestComparePoint.x);
        yDist = ABS([(NSValue*)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y - closestComparePoint.y);
        if(sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)) < Pathdistance)
        {
            Pathdistance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist));
            pathClosestIndex = i;
        }
    }

    if(Pathdistance < Controldistance)
    {
        moveControl = NO;
        closestIndex = pathClosestIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        moveControl = YES;
    }




}



- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    pressedPoint = NO;
}



-(void)removeRectangles{
    [self.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];

}

-(void)addrectangle:(CGPoint) center{


    int offset = 8;
    UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y - offset)];
    // # Entry Point with 10px white frame
    [path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y - offset)];
    // # Keeping 10px frame with iPhone's 450 on y-axis
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y + offset)];
    // path2 Substracting 10px for frame on x-axis, and moving 450 in y-axis
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + offset, center.y + offset)];
    // # Moving up to 1st step 10px line, 310px on the x-axis
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + offset, center.y - offset)];
    // # Back to entry point
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y - offset)];

    // 4th Create a CAShapeLayer that uses that UIBezierPath:
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path2 CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

    // 5th add shapeLayer as sublayer inside layer view
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}

-(void)addQuadrectangle:(CGPoint) center{


    int offset = 4;
    UIBezierPath *path2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y - offset)];
    // # Entry Point with 10px white frame
    [path2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y - offset)];
    // # Keeping 10px frame with iPhone's 450 on y-axis
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y + offset)];
    // path2 Substracting 10px for frame on x-axis, and moving 450 in y-axis
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + offset, center.y + offset)];
    // # Moving up to 1st step 10px line, 310px on the x-axis
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + offset, center.y - offset)];
    // # Back to entry point
    [path2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x - offset, center.y - offset)];

    // 4th Create a CAShapeLayer that uses that UIBezierPath:
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path2 CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

    // 5th add shapeLayer as sublayer inside layer view
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}

-(int)findOrigoInX
{
    int closestToX = [(NSValue *)[pathPoints firstObject] CGPointValue].x;
    for(int i = 1; i < [pathPoints count]; i++)
    {
        if([(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x < closestToX)
        {
            closestToX = [(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x;
        }
    }

        return closestToX;
}

-(int)findOrigoInY
{
    int closestToY = [(NSValue *)[pathPoints firstObject] CGPointValue].y;
    for(int i = 1; i < [pathPoints count]; i++)
    {
        if([(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y > closestToY)
        {
            closestToY = [(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y;
        }
    }

    return closestToY;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)generateKoordinateArray
{
    NSLog(@"count in pathPoints : %lu", (unsigned long)[pathPoints count]);
    NSMutableArray *storeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    BezierCsvFormat *storeBezier = [[BezierCsvFormat alloc] init];

    NSString *stringValueX;
    NSString *stringValueY;

    int xOffset = [self findOrigoInX];
    NSLog(@"x offset : %d", xOffset);

    int yOffset = [self findOrigoInY];
    NSLog(@"y offset : %d", yOffset);

    for(int i = 1; i < [pathPoints count]; i++)
    {
        storeBezier = [[BezierCsvFormat alloc] init];
        stringValueX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i-1] CGPointValue].x - xOffset];
        stringValueY = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ABS((int)[(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i-1] CGPointValue].y - yOffset)];
        [storeBezier setp0:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",stringValueX, stringValueY]];


        stringValueX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[(NSValue *)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i-1] CGPointValue].x - xOffset];
        int multiplicator = 1;
        if((int)[(NSValue *)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i-1] CGPointValue].y > yOffset)
        {
            multiplicator = multiplicator * -1;
        }
        stringValueY = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", multiplicator * ABS((int)[(NSValue *)[controlPoints objectAtIndex:i-1] CGPointValue].y - yOffset)];
        [storeBezier setp1:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",stringValueX, stringValueY]];


        stringValueX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)[(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].x - xOffset];
        stringValueY = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", ABS((int)[(NSValue *)[pathPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue].y - yOffset)];
        [storeBezier setp2:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",stringValueX, stringValueY]];



        [storeArray addObject:storeBezier];

    }
        NSLog(@"count in storeArray : %lu", (unsigned long)[storeArray count]);
    return storeArray;
}

- (NSMutableArray*)printCoordinateSystem
{


    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [self generateKoordinateArray];

    return tempArray;
    NSLog(@"count in tempArray : %lu", (unsigned long)[tempArray count]);

    for(int i = 0; i < [tempArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"p0 : %@ p1 : %@ p2 : %@", [(BezierCsvFormat*)[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] getp0], [(BezierCsvFormat*)[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] getp1], [(BezierCsvFormat*)[tempArray objectAtIndex:i] getp2]);
    }
}




-(void)resetView{

    @try {
        [path removeAllPoints];
        pathPoints = [NSMutableArray array];

        [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        [self.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        [self resetView];
    }
    @finally {

    }

}
```

Comment: If you turn on NSZombie debugging, that should cause an exception when the error happens, which'll inform you about which object has been deallocated. that should make it much easier to debug.

Comment: Your `resetView` method looks pretty suspicious as well w/ it's try/catch recursion going on. any chance you're calling this method on a background thread? if so, UIKit isn't thread safe and i could imagine the removeFromSuperviews causing the issue you're seeing.